# What are the performance and resource costs of property observers in Swift?

Tags: swift, mvvm, key-value-observing

In terms of performance and resources, just how expensive are property observers in Swift? I'm very interested in comparing design patterns and the MVVM pattern raises some suspicion with me for its abundant use of property observers. Like in nature, there are no free lunches in programming and if something seems too good to be true, there has to be some significant tradeoff.

For instance, if a property in a random object (like a view controller) changes, a property observer can capture that change and post a notification to any object (however "far away") listening for that notification. This almost seems too good to be true, and it could completely replace the need for delegates. And so if we did this to every property in an entire app, what would the general performance/resource cost be?

Doesn't the pattern of creating twice as many objects (one extra view-model for every existing view controller) tightly bound together by property observers completely defy the practice of loose coupling?

Comment: Re performance impact, the difference is not generally observable. I would be concerned if using this pattern in some incredibly high volume environment, but most of the time, it’s just not material. I wouldn’t lose any sleep over that. Re the broader architectural concerns, you just have to weigh these considerations against all the benefits that it brings to the table.

Comment: Have you done you own testing? Do you have a *specific* example you are thinking about? SO is about these things, not "theory" - at least in general. Property observers exist in virtually all languages nowadays. As such, do you think you've asked a question - as worded - appropriate for SO?

Comment: @dfd there is nothing theoretical about my question. The question is specifically about the performance and resource impact of property observing in Swift.